# SQL Server : change automatically generated Job Notification Email

Tags: sql-server, email, jobs

Is it possible to change the automatically generated job notification email? In my case it generates a mail like this (translated by me):

Subject:

```
SQLServer-Jobsystem: 'JobName' at \\ServerName\DatabaseName finished.
```

Body:

```
JobExecution:   'JobName' executed at '12.12.2014' 14:48:04.
Duration:   0 Hours, 0 Minutes, 1 Seconds
STATUS:     Successfully Finished
Messages:   The Job was successful. The Job has been executed by Schedule (Su 7:00) Last Executed Step 1 (JobName).
```

I want to define the subject and body by my self, but I cant find any stored procedures for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know of no way to modify the built in emails SQL Agent sends.  The template is hard coded, as far as I'm aware.

You could use [customized notifications](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2863/customized-sql-agent-job-notifications/).  Basically, add a step after the last step in SQL Agent, then use that step to send the success email.  Since it's the last step and every previous step said "Success: Go to next" and "Failure: Quit reporting failure", the only way the last step is running is if everything was a success.  Now your new step can itself send the email for success.

You could, theoretically, do the same for failure notices, but the logic gets a bit hairy then since the're not very good branching logic support in SQL Agent.

Comment: Thats not possible for me. The reason why I wanted to change the template is because the mail is not always send. My job sends a mail and if finished it sends a mail from the notification to check if both mails worked. Somtimes they do not, then I have to check the other jobs(backup etc.)